# Overwrite file Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet API Script.  I want to 1. Export to csv 2. Overwrite existing file.

I want to overwrite the existing file in my drive folder. Right now, its making copies of the file. How I can overwrite ?

```
function makeCopy() {

// generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

// gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();


var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("1JGHoshv6");

// gets the current Google Sheet file
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())

// makes copy of "file" with "name" at the "destination"
file.makeCopy(name, destination);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? You want to overwrite the existing CSV file by new CSV data using Google Apps Script. I could understand your goal like this. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the relationship between your script and your goal? And also, where do you want to retrieve the CSV data? I couldn't understand about your script.

Comment: My code is in the google sheets file : Google sheet ->Tools ->Script editor. this export is done every hour with a trigger. So I don't want duplicates files in my Google Drive. I want one updated export every hour...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, the target file is not CSV file, it is Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes sorry thats correct! i will modify

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to overwrite the existing Google Spreadsheet in the specific folder by the active Google Spreadsheet. I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the overwrite you expect? You want to use the same filename while the file ID is changed? Or you want to use the same filename and same file ID? How about this?

Comment: Thanks! Discussing about it made me realize, that I want to export in a csv and yes to use the same filename and same file ID.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, you want to overwrite the existing CSV file by new CSV data using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike, the "CSV" note is gone from the topic now =(

Comment: Yes, i modify again. So yes Google Sheet -> CSV -> Trigger and overwrite file

Comment: @contributorpw Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about OP's goal.

Comment: @Simon GIS Thank you for replying. As the result, my understanding in my 1st comment was correct?

Comment: Yes,My Goal is to have an hourly export CSV format without any duplicates files in my drive folder.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that the destination file is the CSV file. But I couldn't understand about the source data. I apologize for my poor English skill. But I think that [the contributorpw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61200862/7108653) will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. It seems you need push a CSV data to the current sheet. You can use Advanced Sheets Service

```js
var CSV_FILE_ID = '1G9eI5bj_jYQz_a_mk4t5mmLJsgwOpP8q'; // Your CSV file or data
var SHEETID = '0';

/**
 * User action. Import the CSV file
 */
function userActionImportFromCSV() {
  var res = importFromCSV_(
    CSV_FILE_ID,
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(),
    SHEETID
  );
  Logger.log(res);
}

/**
 * Imports the CSV file to the Sheet
 * @param {string} csvId CSV file Id
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId  Spreadsheet Id
 * @param {string} sheetId Sheet Uid
 * @return {any}
 */
function importFromCSV_(csvId, spreadsheetId, sheetId) {
  // Get CSV data

  var data = DriveApp.getFileById(csvId)
    .getBlob()
    .getDataAsString();

  // Clear the Sheet
  var updateCellsRequest = Sheets.newUpdateCellsRequest();
  updateCellsRequest.fields = 'userEnteredValue';
  updateCellsRequest.range = { sheetId: sheetId };
  batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(
    {
      updateCells: updateCellsRequest,
    },
    spreadsheetId
  );

  // Paste the data
  var pasteDataRequest = Sheets.newPasteDataRequest();
  pasteDataRequest.coordinate = {
    sheetId: SHEETID,
    rowIndex: 0,
    columnIndex: 0,
  };
  pasteDataRequest.data = data;
  pasteDataRequest.type = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES;
  pasteDataRequest.delimiter = ',';

  var batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse = batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(
    {
      pasteData: pasteDataRequest,
    },
    spreadsheetId
  );
  return batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
}

/**
 *
 * @param {object} request Request object
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId Spreadsheet Id
 * @return {object} BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse
 */
function batchUpdateSpreadsheet_(request, spreadsheetId) {
  var resource = {
    requests: [],
  };
  resource.requests.push(request);
  var batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    resource,
    spreadsheetId
  );
  return batchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse;
}
```

### If some one need export to CSV also

So if it is a really a real file then you can

```js
function overWriteFileSample() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('ABCD1234'); // Your CSV file
  const content = new Date().toISOString();
  file.setContent(content);
}
```

If it's a Sheet. Then before all you have to export the file to CSV. After that you can `setContent`.

For sample this works fine

```js
function run(){
  exportToCSV_('ABCD1234', spreadsheetId, sheetId)
}


/**
 *
 * @param {string} csvId
 * @param {string} spreadsheetId
 * @param {string | number} sheetId
 */
function exportToCSV_(csvId, spreadsheetId, sheetId) {
  var url = Utilities.formatString(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export?id=%s&exportFormat=csv&gid=%s',
    spreadsheetId,
    sheetId
  );

  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
  }).getBlob();

  DriveApp.getFileById(csvId).setContent(data.getDataAsString());
}
```

Based on the snippet [sheets/export-import-to-csv](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/sheets/export-import-to-csv)

Comment: awesome stuff! let me get back to you

Comment: Exception: We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 28, file "Code") https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/sheets/export-import-to-csv/index.js

Comment: Exception: We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again.
    at importFromCSV_(Code:28:6)
    at userActionImportFromCSV(Code:8:13)

Comment: Wow! I didn't see that yet! So maybe try again later? Also I have to know do you enable the advanced services https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/sheets/export-import-to-csv/appsscript.json ?

Comment: Where this part of code going?? on top of my code for exporting?

Comment: @SimonGIS I made a sample for you https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzPdrHKVZ49b9zuQs3O1l5Aj24ibZo8DeEDA5y4j640/edit?usp=sharing Make a copy. Add to the code your CSV file ID. Refresh the sheet. Run the script from the custom menu. It should work bidirectional (import/export)

Comment: how I can select specific columns in the export?

Comment: The best way for this it's create a sheet with specific columns getting via formulas like `FILTER` and `QUERY`

Comment: Thanks for your advice my current datasheet is quite heavy, So lets say i create another datasheets with Filter and Query. Everytime a change is made in the first datasheet, this will automatically update in the second datasheet without opening it right?

Comment: Yep, I suppose that this will always be recounted before being imported.

Comment: @contrubutorpw If i want to select the 3rd tab to export of my spreadsheet how do i do that? For now it export by default the first one

Comment: Found it : var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
var secondSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[3];

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(secondSheet).getRange('A1:C8928').activate();